# Typo3: Javascript problem. Fluid interprets arguments variable as string

Tags: javascript, typo3, fluid

I have got a problem using ajax calls to one of my controller actions.
In the response section, I'm building an "html object" with a link to the desired action and later use .html( html_object) to put it inside the dom.

```
const uid = item.uid; //simple int value

html_object= '' +
... +

'<f:link.action controller="FrontendVideo" action="show" arguments="{videoUid :'+uid.toString()+'}">'

+ ...
```

Now I'm trying to pass the uid to this string, but Typo3 interprets the +uid.toString as a string (later inside the dom I see that the value is uid.toString()) and therefore I get an validation error. The behaviour is super strange and unexpected. I tried various methods (also without toString() since it should not be necessary) but Typo3 does interpret the passed variable simply as string.

If I hardcode the value inside, everything works fine of course.

```
html_object= '' +
... +

'<f:link.action controller="FrontendVideo" action="show" arguments="{videoUid :123}">'

+ ...
```

Any solutions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is uid defined? can you show more code?

Comment: @tire0011: The uid is just an int value. I added it to the code snippet.

Comment: What when you try .. const viedeoUid = uid.toString();  and in the string arguments="{videoUid :'+viedeoUid +'}"

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately.. problem has something to do with the way the fluid code is interpreted.

Comment: when you only set html_object= 
'<f:link.action controller="FrontendVideo" action="show" arguments="{videoUid : '+ uid.ToString()+ '}">'; without the other parts, same result?

Comment: If I hardcode the value inside, everything works fine of course. As I mentioned. 

If you mean without the rest of the string, same result yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be working.
you mix computing of the server with computing from the client.

Fluid is rendered on the server while javascript is executed in the client.
And it is done at different times.

The Fluid of your javascript is not rendered when the Ajax-call is done, but when the initial page is rendered. then there is no possibility to insert a (javascript) variable which gets it's value later on at the client. So the server can only insert the 'variable' as a string, as it is no variable yet.

---

Another way would be if you manage to prepare your Ajax call to provide the server with some fluid which gets rendered inside the Ajax response. **BUT you don't want that mechanism in your website.** That would be like an SQL-injection as everyone could insert any kind of Fluid-statement in your server.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of :/ Well in that case I have to be a little more creative and find another solution. Thank you!

Comment: what a bout an ajax-call where you select the kind of template and the id? like `{type:'video', uid:123}`? and on the server you can insert the uid into the selected Fluid template.